# How to have v-for loop nested in an other v-for loop in vuejs working?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a types variable that is an array of objects. Each object has 2 properties name and content.
The second property content is an array of object with only one property : `name`.

When **displayed in the template** with {{types}} I see this:

```
[ { "name": "Base", "content": [ { "name": "Base (Lager/Pilsner)" }, { "name": "Base (Pale)" }, { "name": "Base (Pale Ale)" }, { "name": "Base (Wheat)" }, { "name": "Base (Rye" }, { "name": "Base (Wheat)" } ] },

{ "name": "Kilned", "content": [ { "name": "Munich" }, { "name": "Vienna" }, { "name": "Aromatic" }, { "name": "Amber|Biscuit|Victory" }, { "name": "Brown Malt" } ] }, 

{ "name": "Stewed", "content": [ { "name": "Caramel|Crystal" }, { "name": "Dextrin" }, { "name": "Special Belge" }, { "name": "Honey Malt" } ] },

{ "name": "Roasted/Torrefied", "content": [ { "name": "Pale Chocolate" }, { "name": "Chocolate" }, { "name": "Black Wheat" }, { "name": "Roast Barley" }, null, { "name": "Roast Rye" }, { "name": "BLack Malt" } ] },

 { "name": "Others", "content": [ { "name": "Acidulated" } ] } ]
```

Here is my template

```
            <div class="h-3/4 overflow-auto">

             <div v-for="(group,index) in types">
                <FermentableTypeItem
                 @updateModel="updateModel"
                 :key="index"
                 :type_name="group.name"
                 :group_name="group.name"
                 :state="group.state"
                ></FermentableTypeItem>
                {{group.content}}
                
                 <FermentableTypeItem
                    v-for=" (t,index) in group.content"
                    @updateModel="updateModel"
                    :key="index"
                    :type_name="t.name"
                    :group_name="group.name"
                ></FermentableTypeItem>
                 
             </div>
               
            </div>
```

As you can see I want to add a special [1] FermentableTypeItem for each first level element and then loop on this first level element 's content property to add a list of normal [2] FermentableTypeItem.

> Note 1: special means that the group_name and the type_name are
> identical
>
> Note 2: normal means the the group_name and the type_name are
> different

It works and display the various `FermentableTypeItem` s **but only when I don't use the t variable** in the second loop
If I use it, the app crashes saying the **t is undefined**.
Could somebody help me fixing this error ? May be it's obvious but I cannot see what is wrong.

Comment: One more observation, `:key` should be unique. Hence, instead of `index` we can rename it something else in second iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `null` content object present. So remove `null` content from response your or check `null` `v-if="t != null"` like below.

```
<div v-for=" (t,index) in group.content" :index="index">
    <FermentableTypeItem v-if="t != null"
    @updateModel="updateModel"
    :key="index"
    :type_name="t.name"
    :group_name="group.name"
    ></FermentableTypeItem>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the trouble.

Comment: @Meaulnes Most welcome.